Undeletion request 23598
The question has been deleted by the community before I want to place a bounty on the question.
https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/23598/conveying-so-bad-its-good-talking-about-movies-tv-shows
Any chance this could be reviewed for undeletion, so that I can place a bounty on the question?

Adding this as a comment instead of an answer, but I think you really should consider editing it to take the comments into account before placing a bounty on it. Do remember that Latin is a dead language and that drop-in desk is a very modern term, so it's probable that no one has coined a term for it yet, let alone made it popular enough to be known outside their immediate circle.

Another option is to write the question anew, but still taking into account all the comments. Others might weigh in with more or different thoughts.

I would not undelete it.
It was deleted by the automatic system due to being a month old and having a negative score and no answers, and I find that to be a reasonable deletion condition.
(I may misremember the exact conditions for deletion, but they are irrelevant.)
I actually think you already got your answer:
There's probably no such term.
If you think that is not the case, you should really explain why you think otherwise.
What would be comparable terms in other languages?
Are there things in the ancient world with similar features?
What do you want the translation for and what do you require of it?
I agree with the comments by cmw, and I reiterate also the comments from the question itself:

Languages have words for things they need to express; what makes you think that Latin would have a word for this?
To continue on the previous comment: I'm very familiar with the concept you describe but I had never heard the term "drop-in desk" used for it. One can try to compose a description in Latin or look for the most similar thing in the Roman world, but I don't think there will be anything you could call "the translation".

If you want to get an answer, I think that the by far best option is to write a new question where you elaborate on the matter, addressing at least all the concerns mentioned.
Yes, every last one, and possibly more if you or others can think of any.
Otherwise it will remain unclear what you are after.

No, I am against writing a new question. I really cannot live without that question for the following reason:
I have asked this question on May 14, when the Latin Stack Exchange site ahs been the featured site.

@Arunabh That's quite a non sequitur. Being a featured site is nigh invisible and utterly irrelevant for all questions our site has seen. I'm not going to continue this conversation any further.
